# Chrome Browser Extension | Javascript: How to autofill multiple sites?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am building a Chrome browser extension that generates random usernames, passwords, emails, and more. I have created an autofill function in the popup.js file that triggers the contentscript.js, which then autofills input fields in the current tab.
However, I am facing a problem as I only know how to autofill one specific site by getting the name of each input field.

As I have said, I only know how to autofill one specific site by getting the name of each input field. I am looking for a more flexible solution that can autofill multiple sites.
Do you have any suggestions or tips for how I can achieve this? I have code snippets below for reference. Thank you in advance for your help!

Here are the codes:
manifest.json

```
{
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "name": "Alias Generator",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "Generates aliases for your personal information",
  "icons": {
    "16": "icons/16.png",
    "48": "icons/48.png",
    "128": "icons/128.png"
  },
  
  "action": {
    "default_icon": "icons/128.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "activeTab",
    "storage",
    "tabs"
  ],
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
      "js": ["contentscript.js"]
    }
  ]
}
```

popup.js (I have included it in popup.html)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#autofill").click(function(){
    var data = {
      username: $("#username").val(),
      email: $("#email").val(),
      pwd: $("#password-input").val(),
      firstname: $("#firstname").val(),
      middlename: $("#middlename").val(),
      lastname: $("#lastname").val(),
      birthdate: $("#birthdate").val(),
      address: $("#address").val(),
      url: $("#url").val()
    };

    console.log("Sending message to content script with data:", data);

    // Send the data to the content script
    chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs){
      chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {type: "autofill", data: data}, function(response){
        console.log(response);
      });
    });
  });
});
```

contentscript.js

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse){
  if(request.type === "autofill"){
    // Get the list of input fields on the current tab
    var inputFields = document.getElementsByTagName('input');

    // Loop through the input fields and fill the ones that match the available data
    for(var i=0; i<inputFields.length; i++){
      if(inputFields[i].type === 'text' && inputFields[i].name === 'user[name]' && request.data.firstname){
        inputFields[i].value = request.data.firstname;
      }
      else if(inputFields[i].type === 'email' && inputFields[i].name === 'user[email]' && request.data.email){
        inputFields[i].value = request.data.email;
      }
      else if(inputFields[i].type === 'password' && inputFields[i].name === 'user[password]' && request.data.pwd){
        inputFields[i].value = request.data.pwd;
      }
    }

    sendResponse({success: true});
  }
});
```

Comment: There are probably other extensions out there that do the same thing. Have you searched for them and found any? Then you can look how they solved this problem.

Comment: Hi, I've tried inspecting autofill extensions but the way they do it is too complex for me. Some of them are not in the same context as mine. Also tried searching online but I can't find anything that can autofill multiple sites with different input field names and ids.